# What are datanucleus DELETEME* tables and when are they CREATED and DROPPED

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, datanucleus

I am getting following exception while executing spark Jobs.

org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusDataStoreException: Exception thrown obtaining schema column information from datastore

Which is caused by
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'hive_metastore.DELETEME1530184568175' doesn't exist

Comment: More than likely to determine the schema/catalog in use when the user doesn't provide it in their configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

```
22/04/10 04:10:30 ERROR Datastore: Error thrown executing CREATE TABLE `DELETEME1649563830414`
(
    `UNUSED` INTEGER NOT NULL
) ENGINE=INNODB : CREATE command denied to user 'someuser'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' for table 'DELETEME1649563830414'
```

since it was for develop, I just granted all privileges

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'%';
```